# The infinite intersection of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the infinite intersection of finite sets a finite set? Could you give me some examples or counterexamples?

Comment: A subset of a finite set is finite, and an intersection of sets is a subset of each set it is an intersection of.

Comment: Notice that the elements in the intersection must be in all the subsets, then let be $A = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_i$, you have $|A| \leq |E_i|$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is the intersection of finite sets, it must be finite. Or you really mean the union of finite sets ?